# tensorflow - resize dimension

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I am new to tensorflow and wondering if it is possible to resize a single dimension within a tensor.

let's I have a given tensor t:

```
t = [[1, 10], [2, 20]]
shape(t) = [2, 2]
```

now I want to modify the shape of this tensor, so that:

```
shape(t) = [2, 3]
```

So far I just found the functions:

- reshape --> this function is able to reshape the tensor in such a way, that the total number of dimensions stays the same (as far as i understood)

  ```
  shape(t) = [1, 3] | [3, 1] | [4]
  ```
- expand_dims --> this function is able to add a new 1-dimensional dimension

  ```
  shape(t) = [1, 2, 2] | [2, 1, 2] | [2, 2, 1]
  ```

Is a function for my described purpose in place? If not: Why? (Maybe it doesn't make sense to have such a function?)

Kind regards

Comment: From (2,2) to (2,3), you have two more elements in the tensor. Where should they come from or how should they be calculated?

Comment: Could you describe what you're trying to achieve by doing that and what data should fill the extra space? If you want to fill the extra space with zeros, you can use tf.pad like this: ```tf.pad(t, [[0, 0], [0, 1]])```

Comment: Thank you, tf.pad is the one i searched for.

Answer (score 0):

use `tf.concat` can do it. Here is an example.

```
import tensorflow as tf

t = tf.constant([[1, 10], [2, 20]], dtype=tf.int32)
# the new tensor w/ the shape of [2]
TBA_a = tf.constant([3,30], dtype=tf.int32)
# reshape TBA_a to [2,1], then concat it to t on axis 1 (column)
new_t = tf.concat([t, tf.reshape(TBA_a, [2,1])], axis=1)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print(new_t.eval())
```

It will give us

```
[[ 1 10  3]
 [ 2 20 30]]
```